# How to separate letters, numbers, undescore and dash from string PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-split

I am trying to split a string like this:

```
$string = letters1234_1-someMoreText;
```

Output should be:

```
$string_split [letters1234, 1, someMoreText];
```

Only if string matches the desired patern.

```
if(preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)([0-9])([_])([0-9])([-])/', $string)) {
       $string_split = preg_split('/^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)([_])([0-9])([-])([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/', $string);
}else{
       $string_split = $string;
}
```

This seems to be much more complicated than I have comprehend by now, but so far being stuck..

Comment: `preg_match()` is not the most ideal tool for this task, use `preg_split()`. https://3v4l.org/J7U6H  If your task is about validation AND extraction AND your input strings are predictably formatted, then `sscanf()` might the best tool https://3v4l.org/ORJW4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may actually use your current regex (and add `.*` to it to match the string tail) with a [`preg_match` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and use *capturing groups* to capture the parts you need to get as a result. In your case, just check with `preg_match` and once a match is found, assign the found captures to the `$string_split` variable:

```
$string = "letters1234_1-someMoreText";
$string_split = $string;
if (preg_match('/^([A-Z]+[0-9]+)_([0-9])-(.*)/si', $string, $matches)) {
    array_shift($matches);
    $string_split = $matches;
}
print_r($string_split);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/upv9hC) yielding

```
Array
(
    [0] => letters1234
    [1] => 1
    [2] => someMoreText
)
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z]+[0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more letters followed with 1+ digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `([0-9])` - Capturing group 2: a digit
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(.*)` - any 0+ chars

The `is` modifiers make the pattern case insensitive and `.` may match line break chars.